# Bigram of words in list

Tags: python

I have a sentence:

```
 "this is a test string for bigram pair generation"
```

I need to form bigram pairs in python and store them in a variable.
condition: a word can only be allowed to make pair with forward next 3 words.

Here is what I want:

```
 [["this", "is"], ["this", "a"], ["this", "test"], ["is", "a"], ["is", "test"], ["is", "string"], ["a", "test"], ["a", "string"], ["a", "for"], ["test", "string"], ["test", "for"], ["test", "bigram"], ["string", "for"], ["string", "bigram"], ["string", "pair"], ["for", "bigram"], ["for", "pair"], ["for", "generation"], ["bigram", "pair"], ["bigram", "generation"], ["pair", "generation"]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: nothing, dont know how to do it

Comment: Split it into two tasks: 1. Take a pair for example `('this', ['is', 'a', 'test'])` and return the bigrams that start with the first element and end with a member of the second element.  2. Take a string and form the input pairs for task 1.  `str.split` and list slicing will likely help there

Comment: As it seems you are new to Stack Overflow, I recommend you read the [instructions on how to make questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Tip: you should have tried to solve your problem before asking for a solution. In general, it is a good practice to show you have tried hard to solve it, or to find a solution elsewhere before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a list of all words in a sentence using the `.split()` method and then loop over it, adding every appropriate pair into the resulting list:

```
sentence = "this is a test string for bigram pair generation"

words = sentence.split()
result = []

for i in range(len(words)):
    for j in range(1, 4):
        if i + j < len(words):
            result.append([words[i], words[i+j]])

print(result)
```

As the appropriate paired word is only `1` to `3` words forward, the `j` variable in the inner `for` loops is used to ensure it.